# How to view older stories in Facebook news feed? [Add Friends to See More Stories]

Tags: facebook, news-feed

The problem:

- View Facebook news feed
- Scroll down the page
- "Infinite scroll" loads about 100 posts (10 days)
- No more posts are shown, instead a box titled "Add Friends to See More Stories" is shown

It appears to be impossible to go back further in time. In other words, Facebook seems to limit the number of posts that you can view. This has been a problem I've seen for 6 months or longer. In my current case I haven't checked Facebook for about 3 months, so only being able to see 10 days worth of past posts is not useful.

I've tried using F.B. Purity and Social Fixer, and using a completely clean browser profile, and switching between but Most Recent and Top Stories, and the problem still occurs. The number of friends doesn't seem to be relevant since users with 4,000+ friends report the same issue.

Other users report the same problem:

https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10205280399081185
https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10203669060999418

but I cannot find any in-depth analysis of the problem online. This appears to be an artificial limit imposed by Facebook. Is there a workaround? Continuing to make calls to the "Infinite scroll" data source with the correct magic parameters will likely return older stories, but I have not tried to decipher the query format used for those calls.

Answer (score -1):

Rustic Workaround: Create a new Friends Group called e.g., "AllFriends". Put all of your friends in the group. Use this view to see all posts.